# How to update the particular list item in list view in android

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I have an application where some items appear in a list view. Now I want to add some new items. I want to show the word "New" for newly-added items, and when a new item is clicked that "New" word should disappear. How should I do this?

Comment: refer to 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103356/android-remove-item-from-custom-listview-on-button-click/23103444?noredirect=1#comment35315432_23103444

Answer (score 1):

Follow that answer that is use for gridview you can also same for listview, notifyDataSetChanged();

[Android Gridview is not refreshed while pressing back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337238/android-gridview-is-not-refreshed-while-pressing-back-button/23337384#23337384)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
listview.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know how to use notifyDatesetchanged(). I want to show the word "New" for newly added items. pls give some examples for that?

Answer (score 0):

Update the data backing your list adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

On selecting particular item from the list, you can change the status in the model class of that item ,from new to empty string "". And then depending on this value you can set the visibility of view if you want.

As the model in the datalist is updated you need to notify your adapter that underlying data has beeen changed.  So call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

**UPDATE:**

`notifyDataSetChanged()` -
Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

When an Adapter is constructed, it holds the reference for the List that was passed in. If you pass-in a List that was a member of an Activity, and change some of the data later, the Adapter is still holding a reference to the original List. The Adapter does not know you changed the List in the Activity. Hence call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on Adapter.

Comment: Pls explain what is the use of notifyDataSetChanged()?